# Mount volume in k8s cluster - Connection Refused

Tags: kubernetes, nfs, kubernetes-pod

We are using private cluster.
I could mount nfs folder from the Pod using mount command but when I mount it using volume I got Connection Refused:

```
volumes:
  - name: nfs-share
    nfs:
      path: /mount
      server: my.nfs.com

Mounting command: systemd-run
Mounting arguments: --description=Kubernetes transient mount for /var/lib/kubelet/pods/bd7c2a60-64e7-4423-b6b8-7b4621f2015e/volumes/kubernetes.io~nfs/nfs-share --scope -- mount -t nfs my.nfs.com:/mount /var/lib/kubelet/pods/bd7c2a60-64e7-4423-b6b8-7b4621f2015e/volumes/kubernetes.io~nfs/nfs-share
Output: Running scope as unit run-211758.scope.
mount.nfs: Connection refused
```

I'm confused what's the difference between those mounts and wghat could be an issue? The mount command from Pod is the same, FW rules and NetworkPolicy are in place.

Comment: how do you whitelist IPs in NFS server? most problably not all k8s IPs are whitelisted

Comment: We have firewall rules between k8s and nfs and label pods with FW group labels

Comment: but the NFS request comes not from a pod but from a node, check your kubelet logs, you need to whitelist nodes as well

Comment: @AntonMatsiuk - Thanks. That was the cause.